# Use <a href> link and <onclick> function together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make this a tag working with href and onClick function? 
(The onClick should run first then href)

Version 1

```
<a href="#" id="myHref">Click me</a>

$("#myHref").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
     window.location = "http://www.google.com";

});
```

Version 2

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return myFunction();">Link</a>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5"; 
}
```

Comment: why do you need to change something that's about to disappear anyway?

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code, this is confusing, where is `myDiv` the `<div>`? Please add the rest of your code and/or update your explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, the description is kind of cryptic.

Comment: well if you follow the link, it makes no sense to update the page because the page is exiting. If you want to pause, you need to cancel the click, and use a setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the click, call your animation, and then add a delay to follow the link.

```
$("#myHref").on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //cancel the default click action
    document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
    var url = this.href;  //get the href of the clicked link
    window.setTimeout( function () {  //delay setting the location
        window.location.href = url;
    }, 5000); //number of milliseconds to wait
});
```

The setTimeout will allow the animation to happen. Adjust the time to whatever works.

Answer (score -1):

`href` is not an event, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Your `onclick` is running first, but you should `return false` if you don't want the href to activate.

Version 1

```
$("#myHref").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    return false;
});
```

Also, `document.getElementById(".myDiv")` should not have a dot in the name. (Assuming you are wanting to get `<div id="myDiv">`. If you have jQuery, just use `$("#myDiv")`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use version 1, just add `event.preventDefault()' to the handler:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="myHref">Click me</a>

$("#myHref").on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById(".myDiv").style.flexGrow = "5";
     window.location = event.currentTarget.href;
});
```